# Extract large area from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm trying to export all objects of East Kazakhstan region(as in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmy5M.png)) from OSM file into separate pbf/osm file. What I'm trying to do is extract data from kazakhstan-latest.osm.pbf file by using osmconvert and osmfilter commands, but seems like it doesn't do what I would like to get.

After running the command:

```
./osmfilter kaz.o5m --verbose --keep="admin_level=4 and name=Восточно-Казахстанская\ область" -o=east2.osm
```

I see that my extracted file is only 3.1 Mb which is definitely small for such area.

```
-rw------- 1 sp sp 3.1M Aug 31 16:45 east2.osm
```

[image: East Kazakhstan]

Comment: can you add some explanation as to what you actual want to extract, I can confirm that following your command does give a small file of polylines in Western Kazakhstan and a few points (mostly on the western edge of the polylines)

Comment: I would recommend you use a tool call JOSM.

Comment: I need all objects that is actually located in the East Kazakhstan polygon.

Comment: I guess JOSM can't handle large areas of map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask osmfilter to keep everything that has admin_level 4 and a certain name. That is **NOT** everything **inside** that border line which you intend to get.

Instead, use **osmconvert** to clip to the region of interest from the .pbf file:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Clipping_based_on_a_Polygon

You need to convert the border (which you already have filtered) to `polygon style` with one of the softwares listed at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Polygon_Filter_File_Format#Converting_to.2Ffrom_POLY_format .