# Extract Certain Elements from Global OSM Database

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, waterways

The goal is to find all waterways in Open Street Maps globally.

This is the [equivalent](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/vK0) for a random area in China in overpass turbo. Instead of doing it for this bounded area, I want to query globally.

Overpass turbo gets overloaded by a global query but I found [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) in a [related](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209026/extract-large-area-from-osm) [related2](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/713/how-to-extract-partial-data-for-large-regions) question which seem to be able to get the job done.

`wget -O- https://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/planet-latest.osm.bz2 | bzcat | osmosis --rx - <filter args here> --wx my-compressed-output.osm.gz`

I struggle however in translating the overpass query to the osmosis query and got lost in osmosis documentation.

How would I filter the waterways in osmosis? I think I need --way-key (--wk) or --way-key-value (--wkv) but like to check before executing a massive query.(50GB download)

Alternative solutions (non osmosis) are welcome too.

[image]

Comment: I would start with a small country extract from http://download.geofabrik.de/ before applying any filter logic to a planet size file. In addition, osmium-tool along with PBF file format are more efficient for the task at hand.

Comment: ... or try https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter as alternative to osmosis.

Comment: any thoughts on the differences between osmosis and Osmfilter?

Comment: "but like to check before executing a massive query.(50GB download)" I would test it on a smaller download

Answer (score 0):

You might wan to try

```
--tf accept-relations waterway=* --used-way --used-node
```

or alternatively *accept-ways*